# Does smoke grenade triggers alert or alarm?

Tags: phantom-doctrine

Per the description, it blocks the line of sight, but if I use it, will it trigger the alarm or alert the guards? Or will it just cause them to not be able to hit me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made one smoke grenade and tested it.

Using the smoke grenade DOES end the Infiltration phase, alarm the guards, and start the conflict/combat phase.